# Java: How to start some asyncronous operations and update the ui from other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, refresh, freeze

I have a little problem, now I have to work on a small Java project. I'm trying to run a few threads from Button event handler; then the last one of the threads must update TextArea on the UI. The threads are doing computational stuff work. The most important part is to make the UI woks fine - I don't want to freeze the UI and of course I want to update the UI's TextArea from one of the other threads at regular intervals (not the ui's one). So here is a part of my code:

Inside Button's the event handler I'm starting these 4 threads:

```
Thread generate = new CombinaMaker();
generate.run();

Thread forward = new TranslateForward();
forward.run();

Thread backward = new TranslateBackward();
backward.run();

Thread refresh = new Refresher();
refresh.run();
```

I want the threads to work simultaneously. The Refresher thread must update the UI TextArea component at regular intervals.

So, here is how I update the UI from Refresher thread:

```
public static void updateProgress() 
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {   
         public void run() 
         {
             //HERE
             //I have a loop that have to be looping at every 500 ms
         }
     }
}
```

My qustion is: am I supposed to do that link this? I need to be simple and effective. This loop is making me sad because it must be looping as long as the application works. May be this is the reason of freezing the UI? I know that I am making big error somewhere, but at this moment I can't find it alone. May be you can suggest me some simple solution. And the last think - the first 4 threads: I want to start them 'simultaneously', without freezing my UI. Is that way (starting them like this from the event handler...) the correct one or may be there is better? Thanks a lot friends!

PS. If the refreshing the UI through my 'refresher' thread is hard work I am ready for a compromise variant - Update the UI through his owns thread (UI thread). But in this case may be I must use some 'time shooting mechanism' - avoiding the freezing of the UI. What are you thinking?

Comment: What is the problem you are having, specifically, with your code? Using other threads or TimerTasks is basically what you have to do, yes.

Comment: the loop in update progress - how to avoid freezing the UI? Timer Tasks?

Comment: This is probably terrible advice, but I've passed in references of view objects into other threads, then just have those threads append data to the view directly.  Works good enough for small programs. Not sure I'd release it in a product or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is your algorithm. Instead of

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {   
    public void run() {
        //HERE
        //I have a loop that have to be looping at every 500 ms
    }
}
```

You should have

```
// HERE
// I have a loop that have to be looping at every 500 ms
// and when something must be updated in the GUI:
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {   
    public void run() {
        // update the GUI as fast as possible
    }
});
```

i.e.

```
while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(500L);
    String update = getUpdate();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {   
        public void run() {
            textArea.append(update);
        }
    });
}
```

The runnable passed to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` is executed in the event dispatch thread. It must not execute long-running tasks. Looping endlessly is a very long running task.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to loop in the runnable you pass to invokeAndDoLater. See this for an example: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml

Comment: The link given, although it will successfully blind the OP, says nothing about loops inside of runnables. ASAIK there is nothing wrong with having a loop in a runnable, which is a just another thread as far as the system is concerned. The only issue is that it is synchronous with event dispatch, so if the loop does not exit or yield(), then it will block the event dispatch.

Comment: Many swing objects are not synchronized, and therefore it is important to not update them from other threads. The purpose of InvokeAndDoLater is to get your changes on the AWT update thread (and therefore avoid race conditions with the AWT thread). You never want to do heavy operations on that thread (such as looping) because the UI will freeze until the operation completes. So technically you are right there's nothing to stop you, but it's a very bad idea if you want a responsive UI.

Answer (score 1):

The SwingUtilities.invokeLater has not been designed to invoke long running threads.
One solution to your problem could be [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html).

You could also try to invert the nesting of your loop and SwingUtilities.invokeLater invocation, but the feasibility of this depends on the rest of your code

```
do {
    // Sleep and other stuff
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run()  {
        // Update UI
        }
    });
} while(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to freeze the UI and of course

Thumbs up for not wanting to freeze the UI. Unfortunately the

> I want to update the UI's TextArea from one of the other threads at regular intervals

is not an option. Updating Swing components must be done on the UI thread (the Event Dispatch Thread). Luckily, Swing has a built-in class for updating the UI at regular intervals: the `javax.swing.Timer` class. The `Timer` runs in the background, and executes on the Event Dispatch Thread so it is perfectly suited for this task.